# goyacc: getting context to the yacc parser / no `%param`

Tags: go, yacc

What is the most idiomatic way to get some form of context to the `yacc` parser in [`goyacc`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goyacc), i.e. emulate the [`%param`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Pure-Calling.html) command in traditional `yacc`?

I need to parse to my `.Parse` function some context (in this case including for instance where to build its parse tree).

The `goyacc` `.Parse` function is [declared](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/goyacc/yacc.go#L3416)

```
func ($$rcvr *$$ParserImpl) Parse($$lex $$Lexer) int {
```

Things I've thought of:

- `$$ParserImpl` [cannot be changed](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/goyacc/yacc.go#L3279) by the `.y` file, so the obvious solution (to add fields to it) is right out, which is a pity.
- As `$$Lexer` is an interface, I could stuff the parser context into the Lexer implementation, then force type convert `$$lex` to that implementation (assuming my parser always used the same lexer), but this seems pretty disgusting (for which read non-idiomatic). Moreover there is (seemingly) no way to put a user-generated line at the top of the `Parse` function like `c := yylex.(*lexer).c`, so in the many tens of places I want to refer to this variable, I have to use the rather ugly form `yylex.(*lexer).c` rather than just `c`.
- Normally I'd use [`%param`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Pure-Calling.html) in normal `yacc` / C (well, `bison` anyway), but that doesn't exist in `goyacc`.
- I'd like to avoid postprocessing my generated `.go` file with `sed` or `perl` for what are hopefully obvious reasons.
- I want to be able to (go)yacc parse more than one file at once, so a global variable is not possible (and global variables are hardly idiomatic).

What's the most idiomatic solution here? I keep thinking I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution is to modify `goyacc` ([see this PR](https://github.com/golang/tools/pull/94)) which adds a `%param` directive allowing one or more fields to be added to the `$$ParserImpl` structure (accessible as `$$rcvr` in code). This seems the most idiomatic route. This permits not only passing context in, but the ability for the user to add additional `func()`s using `$$ParserImpl` as a receiver.